# Launch python file from PHP on LINUX server

Tags: php, python, linux

I tried many solutions but nothing it works :

```
echo '<pre>';

shell_exec("python /home/folder/python/mapfile_compress.py");
shell_exec("sudo -u wwwexec python escapeshellcommand(/home/folder/python/mapfile_compress.py) $uid");
shell_exec("sudo chmod +x /home/folder/python/mapfile_compress.py");
system("bash /home/folder/python/mapfile_compress.py");
passthru("bash /home/folder/python/mapfile_compress.py");
passthru("/home/folder/python/mapfile_compress.py");
exec("bash /home/folder/python/mapfile_compress.py");

echo '</pre>';
```

I launched indivdually them but in all cases, Firebug returned : `'<pre>'`

So I tried this code founded on Stack Overflow :

`$command = escapeshellcmd('chmod +x /home/folder/python/mapfile_compress_test.py');
echo $command;
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;`

But firebug returned nothing.
My python file begin with `#!/usr/bin/env python` and if I launch it on server that works !

Do you knwo how can I launch my python file from PHP file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case that's work if I write this code :

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('python /path/to/your/file.py');
exec($command);
```

Answer (score 1):

`chmod` will return 0 on success and > 0 on error.

Make sure that the file is able to run by just executing it as the web user. When +x is properly set, you can execute it by just calling `$ /path/to/your/file.py`, the shebang in the first line in your script `#!/usr/bin/env python` should define the correct python based on your env.

You can test this by running:

```
$ /usr/bin/env python /path/to/your/file.py
```

So check your file permissions to check if the file is executable by the user that runs the php script.

Just to test, you can just print a few lines in your python file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "test line 1"
print "test line 2"
```

Then if you have verified permissions and the correct use of python, you can do this in your php.

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('/path/to/your/file.py');
$output = shell_exec($command); // get all output or use passthrough, exec will only return the last line.
echo "<pre>{$output}</pre>;
```

Comment: Ok, so I try to use chmod from my php file with this code : `chmod ("/home/folder/python/test.py");` but it's the same thing firebug return nothing

Comment: Do you have to use chmod from php? The file you are trying to execute should be available and executable on your server before executing it from php.

Comment: Yes I launched it from PHP file. I can only launch it from PHP file but on my PC, my python file : test.py works

Answer (score 0):

At first, Do you have enabled shell_exec/system/passthru commands in php.ini?

```
shell_exec("python /home/folder/python/mapfile_compress.py");
```

I think, it could be problem with your $PATH. Try something like: (use full path to python)

```
shell_exec("/usr/bin/python /home/folder/python/mapfile_compress.py");
shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/python /home/folder/python/mapfile_compress.py");
```